# Lighting fixture ground wire splicing

Tags: wiring, lighting, grounding

I installed a lighting fixture that hangs from a chain over my dining room table. I realize that I did not hang it long enough so I want to add some chain links which means I have to have more ground wire. I cut the ground wire down already so now it's too short. I have the leftover ground wire I cut, can I just splice the two together to make it longer with a wire nut or something else? Appreciate any feedback thanks

Comment: thank you freeman! thats what i needed to know. I will wire nut it together

Answer (score 3):

You will have to do *something* to lengthen the ground wire, or replace it in its entirety.

Yes, you can simply wire nut the cut off piece to the existing piece. If you're happy with the look of the wire nut there, you're good to go. If not, you may be able to use a crimp connector which would be less visible. Something like [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Tyco-Electronics-14-8-AWG-Copper-Crimp-Sleeves-50-Pack-BM3035-000/205878599) or [this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Ideal-Splice-Cap-Copper-Crimp-Connector-50-per-Box-2011S/305441237) or [these](https://www.mcmaster.com/crimp-on-wire-connectors/noninsulated-crimp-on-butt-splices/)<sup>*</sup> .

---

<sup>*</sup> These are the first and second results listed in a search for "wiring crimp connector". No explicit recommendations of the brands or vendors expressed or implied.